# Using AJAX and JSP to query a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp

Basically, I have a textarea into which the user will type a MySQL query e.g. SELECT * FROM table_names. The query need to be run and the results need to be loaded into a selection field. I have tried various methods but have been unsuccessful, any suggestion to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

mainInterface.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ page language="Java" import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%! 
String gUser;
String gDatabase;
String gPassword;
String gUrl;
String gUrlFront;
String gUrlBack;
%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <link href="main_canvas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabview.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.treeview.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="tabview.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try
        {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
        catch (e)
        {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try
            {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e) 
            {
        try
                {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
                catch (e)
                {
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
        }
            }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
            {
                document.getElementById("boxx").innerHTML= "<option>" + ajaxRequest.responseText + "</option>";
            }
    }
    var age = 1;
    var wpm = 3;
    var sex = 5;
    var queryString = "?dsname=" + gDatabase + "&user=" + gUser + "&pass=" + gPassword + "&u1=" + gUrlFront + "&u2=" + gUrl + "&u2=" + gUrlBack ;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "exeQuery.jsp" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#tree").treeview({
                    collapsed: true,
                    animated: "medium",
                    control:"#sidetreecontrol",
                    prerendered: true,
                    persist: "location"
                });
            })  

            function myFunction()
            {

            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body
            {
                height: 99%;
                width:99%;
                background-color:black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div class="main_body_container" >  <!--Start Main Body-->

                <div class="main_body_container_left"><!--Start Left Pane-->

<jsp:useBean id="NinGoo" scope="session" class="NinGoo.beancode" />
<%
    ResultSet rs = null;    
    Connection conn = null;

        String database = request.getParameter("dsname");
        gDatabase = database;
        String urlfront = "jdbc:mysql://";
        gUrlFront = urlfront;
        String url = request.getParameter("url"); // localhost:3306
        gUrl = url;
        String urlback = "/";        
        gUrlBack = urlback;
        String username = request.getParameter("user");
        gUser = username;
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        gPassword = password;


        NinGoo.setDsname(database);
        NinGoo.setURL(urlfront + url + urlback);
        NinGoo.setusername(username);
        NinGoo.setpassword("");

        conn = NinGoo.getConnection();
        rs = NinGoo.executeSQL( "SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=" + "'" + database + "'"); 

        String result; 
%>

                    <div id="sidetree">

                        <ul class="treeview" id="tree" >
                <h1>LOGO HERE </h1>
                            <li class="expandable"><div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div><span><strong><b><%=database %> (DSNAME)</b> </br></strong></span>

                                <ul style="display: none;">

<%
    while (rs.next())
    {
        result = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");

%>

                                    <li class="expandable"><div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div><span><strong><%=result%></strong></span>

                                        <ul style="display: none;">

<%
        ResultSet columnNames = null;
        String colName;
        String colType;
        columnNames = NinGoo.executeSQL("SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='" + database + "'" + "AND TABLE_NAME='" + result + "'");

        while(columnNames.next())
        {
            colName = columnNames.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
            colType = columnNames.getString("COLUMN_TYPE");

%>
            <table>
            <li><tr><td style="width:60px;"><%=colName%></td><td style="width:20px;"></td><td align="left" style="width:100px;white-space: nowrap;"><%=colType%></td></tr></li>
            </table>
<%
        }
%>
                                        </ul> 
                                    </li>    
<%
    }
%>                            
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--End Left Pane-->

                <div class="main_body_container_right">    <!--Start Right Pane-->
                    <div class="TabView" id="TabView">  <!--Start Tabs Section-->
                         <div class="Tabs" style="width: 400px;"><!--Start Tabs-->
                            <a>Construct Cube</a>
                            <a>Explore Cube</a>
                        </div><!-- End Tabs-->
                        <div class="Pages"> <!--Begin Pages Content-->

                            <div class="Page"> <!-- *** Page1 Start *** -->
                                 <div class="Pad"><!-- Page 1 Start Pad-->
                                        <button onclick="ajaxFunction()" style="float:left;"> Execute Query </button>

                                        <textarea style="float:left;height:400px;width:1000px;resize:none;border: solid black 2px;"> </textarea>


                                        <b style="padding-left:30%; padding-top:20px;">Cube Name </b>
                                        <input id="cubeName" type="text" size="65" style="border:solid black 1px"/>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="height:30px;">
                                                    <!--Empty Cell Used For Alignment-->
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="height:30px;">
                                                    <!--Empty Cell Used For Alignment-->
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button id="dim">Add Dimension</button>
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    <button>Choose Column</button>
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    <!--Empty Column Used For Alignment-->
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    <button>Granularity</button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width:50px;">
                                                    <!--Empty Column Used For Alignment-->
                                                </td>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="height:100px;">
                                                        <!--Empty Cell Used For Alignment-->
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width:200px;;">
                                                        <select size="5" name="selectionField" multiple="yes" > 
                                                            <option >Will List Dimensions</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td >
                                                        <select id="boxx" style="width:200px;" name="selectionField" multiple="yes" > 
                                                            <option >Will List Columns</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="center" style="width:100px;">
                                                        <button> --> </button>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select size="5" name="selectionField" multiple="yes" > 
                                                            <option >Will List Granularity</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="height:30px;">
                                                        <!--Empty Cell Used For Alignment-->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="height:60px;">
                                                        <!--Empty Cell Used For Alignment-->
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button>Aggregate</button>
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td>
                                                        <button>Choose Column</button>
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td>
                                                        <!--Empty Column Used For Alignment-->
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td>
                                                        <button>Measures</button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:50px;">
                                                        <!--Empty Column Used For Alignment-->
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td style="width:200px;;">
                                                        <select size="5" name="selectionField" multiple="yes" > 
                                                            <option >Will List Aggregate </option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select size="5" name="selectionField" multiple="yes" > 
                                                            <option >Will List Columns</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="center" style="width:100px;">
                                                        <button> --> </button>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select size="5" name="selectionField" multiple="yes" > 
                                                            <option >Will List Measures</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="height:50px;">
                                                        <!--Empty Column Used For Alignment-->
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="center" colspan="4">
                                                        <button style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;"> Save Cube </button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </table>                            
                                 </div> <!--End Page1 Pad -->
                            </div> <!--End Page 1 -->

                            <div class="Page"> <!-- *** Page2 Start *** -->
                                 <div class="Pad"><!-- Page2 Start Pad-->
                                 </div> <!--End Page2 Pad -->
                            </div> <!--End Page 2 -->

                        </div> <!--End Pages -->
                    </div><!--End TabView -->
                </div><!--End Right Pane-->

            </div> <!--End Main Body-->


        <script type="text/javascript">
            tabview_initialize('TabView');
        </script>

    </body>
</html>

    <%-- 
    Document   : exeQuery.jsp
    Created on : Nov 28, 2012, 3:07:13 PM
    Author     : Raymond
--%>
```

exeQuery.jsp

```
<%@ page language="Java" import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<jsp:useBean id="NinGoo" scope="session" class="NinGoo.beancode" />
<%
    ResultSet rs = null;    
    Connection conn = null;

        String database = request.getParameter("dsname");
        String urlfront = "jdbc:mysql://";
        String url = request.getParameter("u2"); // localhost:3306
        String urlback = "/";        
        String username = request.getParameter("user");
        String password = request.getParameter("pass");



        NinGoo.setDsname(database);
        NinGoo.setURL(urlfront + url + urlback);
        NinGoo.setusername(username);
        NinGoo.setpassword("");

        conn = NinGoo.getConnection();
        rs = NinGoo.executeSQL( "SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=" + "'" + database + "'"); 


        String result = null; 

        while (rs.next())
        {
            result = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
        }

        out.print(result);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just create a Servlet, use AJAX to post to it, and then send back the information from the query and populate your selection field.  If you want to keep from writing a lot in JS, I suggest you create the fields with names and everything inside the Servlet and send it back to the AJAX object.  Then you can just add what came back to an element in your page.

EDIT: You should never use a JSP to execute your query.